# Pagination, Eloquent outside of Laravel

Tags: laravel, pagination, components, eloquent

Has anyone used Laravels pagination and eloquent outside of the framework.

I get:

```
ReflectionException
Class paginator does not exist
```

When i call:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    // $results = News::get(); <--- this works fine
    $results = News::paginate(6); <--- this does  not

    return $this->renderView('index', compact('results', 'pagination'));
}
```

Everything is autoloading and installed via composer so can't imagine any issues there.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: You can't just use `Paginator` like this way, it has dependencies (Illuminate's Request, View etc) and you should require it using `composer.json` file.